# Why did my xCode archive create an IPA file but last time it created an .APP file

Tags: ios, xcode, export

I'm sharing my iOS app with a developer I'm working with.

I'm using the archive feature of xCode to do this.

The last time I "exported" the archive it created an .APP file which I just shared with him and he installed it in his Iphone Simulator.

This time xcode created a .ipa file. I'm unsure what I did differently to get the .ipa file. I was hoping to get another .app file to share with him.

Any advice on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the `Product` menu at the top and select `Archive`. This will archive the current build and show you all of your Archives in the `Organizer`. In the Organize, press Export, and select the appropriate option. This will place the ipa file onto your desktop.
I didn't get what you did last time. But `Archive` always gives you `.ipa` file